# how to insert emoji in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.10, emoji

I want to insert emoji in a text so I need to know how to insert it. I have tried CTRL+SHIFT+E but it did'nt work. I also have tried WIN+., but that also did'nt work. So I want to know the shortcut to insert emoji in text.

Comment: How about you edit the question and remove the all caps.

Comment: I will do that :) And here is an emoij :)

Answer (score -1):

you can create emoji's using colons, semicolons and parentheses. some examples are:

:)

;)

:(

:D

xD

This method is popular in chat apps like Discord and these are the main emoji's

Comment: Also have a look here: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/06/use-emoji-linux-ubuntu-apps

Comment: that's for 18.04

Comment: 18.04 or later I know, but does it not work on 20.10 too?

Comment: I only use LTS releases, so I don't know. I prefer cross-platform stuff, so that is what I posted :)